# ApiPlatform - filter resources on entity level

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I've a resource based directly on Entity. Entity has relation `ManyToOne` to another table. This table is a dictionary type, has a many types and should be connected something like `entity.dictionary_id=dictionary.ext_id and dictionary.type=2`. At the moment i've random result from external table - it is caused becaus it is a lack of additional condition

Relation connected on two conditions `tableA.field=tableB.field AND tableB.field=2`.

I tried a filters and matching - maybe in wrong way.